# bitbucket - merge branch till specific commit id via REST API

Tags: merge, bitbucket, branch, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-api

for merging two branches via the REST API I follow this advice:

https://community.developer.atlassian.com/t/can-i-merge-two-branches-via-api-call-without-pull-request/19105/4

and do it in 2 steps - create pool request and merge this PR.
it works ok.
but it merges branch1 from the last commit.

now I need merge branch1 to branch2 only till specific commit id from branch1.
in git I can do like:

```
git fetch --all
git merge <commit_id>
git push
```

and after this branch2 has been merged only with commits till commit_id from branch1.
How can I do the same via REST API?
Also, as far I understand - this is NOT cherry-pick because I need merge not only ONE commit but more.

Comment: please, any advices?